# Get total swap size in C on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, swap, ram

I know how to get total RAM by using GlobalMemoryStatus( ) and GlobalMemoryStatusEx( ), but how can I get total swap size on Windows by using C programming ?

Comment: Keep in mind that, by default, the system dynamically adjusts the swap size as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Information on getting pagefile use and limits is in the documentation for the [MEMORYSTATUSEX structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366770(v=vs.85).aspx).

> **ullTotalPageFile**
>
> The current committed memory limit for the system or the current process, whichever is smaller, in bytes. To get the system-wide committed memory limit, call [GetPerformanceInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683210(v=vs.85).aspx).
>
> **ullAvailPageFile**
>
> The maximum amount of memory the current process can commit, in bytes. This value is equal to or smaller than the system-wide available commit value. To calculate the system-wide available commit value, call [GetPerformanceInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683210(v=vs.85).aspx) and subtract the value of CommitTotal from the value of CommitLimit.

[GetPerformanceInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683210(v=vs.85).aspx) fills the [PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684824(v=vs.85).aspx) structure, and the documentation lists all the fields it contains.

The MSDN also has an overview called [Memory Performance Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965225(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: thus , swap size  = totalPageFile ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I know, swap would be equal to: 
`ull*PageFile - ull*Phys`(#1),
 where `*` stands for either `Total` or `Avail`.

This basically works, yet keep in mind that in Windows You can turn swap off - in that case `ull*PageFile` should be the same, as `ull*Phys`, yet there are really tiny differences, which can lead to negative results from (#1) substitution.
These differences come from `ull*PageFile` being `min(user PageFile, system-wide PageFile)`, whereas `ull*Phys` is ofc always system-wide.